# Error while running Scheduled Task from MSBUILD script

Tags: msbuild, scheduled-tasks

I am running a MSBUILD script which disables and enabled a scheduled task from command line.
I am getting following error. No idea, what 'exited with code 1' means. When I try to copy paste the line in command prompt, it works perfectly. I doesnot run in MSBuild script which is in turn called by CruiseControl.NET

SNIPPET FROM MSBUILD file is

ERROR is

The command "C:\WINDOWS\system32\schtasks.exe /S servername /Change /RU SYSTEM /TN "MyScheduledtask" /DISABLE" exited with code 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is failing. Try executing the command directly in the command line to see the error.

If it works try launching msbuild with more log : `msbuild.exe [MSBuildFile.proj] /v:d`

Comment: the command on the command line works perfectly. there is no error.

Comment: Launch MSBuild with more log: msbuild.exe [MSBuildFile.proj] /v:d